# nested dynamic variables on angular

Tags: angularjs, nested

I have  two dynamic variable on my templates and I want  use a dynamic within another dynamic variable on angular.for clear what I want I write down a snippet to clear my aim :

My Goal results of this snippet should be "John Doe", my question is ** how can I use a variable within another variable  in angular ? 
is there any way to achieve this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="person={firstName:'John',var:'Doe'};dynamic='var'">

<p>The name is {{ person.{{dynamic}} }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="person={firstName:'John',var:'Doe'};dynamic='var'">
  <p>The name is {{ person[dynamic] }}</p>
</div>
```